# Spring Data Redis - UUID id - ConverterNotFoundException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data, uuid

I would like to store my entities in Redis with a UUID key:

```
@RedisHash("order")
public class Order {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    ...
}
```

However, I get the following exception with this setup:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.UUID] to type [byte[]]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.toBytes(MappingRedisConverter.java:948) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.lambda$writeInternal$2(MappingRedisConverter.java:592) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:328) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.writeInternal(MappingRedisConverter.java:584) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.write(MappingRedisConverter.java:396) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.MappingRedisConverter.write(MappingRedisConverter.java:122) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisKeyValueAdapter.put(RedisKeyValueAdapter.java:208) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.lambda$update$1(KeyValueTemplate.java:204) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.execute(KeyValueTemplate.java:343) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.KeyValueTemplate.update(KeyValueTemplate.java:204) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.support.SimpleKeyValueRepository.save(SimpleKeyValueRepository.java:103) ~[spring-data-keyvalue-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
...
```

When using String instead of UUID, no such exception appears.

How can I use UUID as ID type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

To be more precise you have to register a CustomConversion bean in your context with the name redisCustomConversions. See this post: [Redis - How to configure custom conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42915576/redis-how-to-configure-custom-conversions)

So in your case it would be something like

```
@Bean
public CustomConversion redisCustomConversions(){
    return new CustomConversions(
        Arrays.asList(new UUIDToStringConverter(), new StringToUUIDConverter()))))
}
```

Original:

I think the easiest way to fix this is to write a type converter for uuid.
Something like a

`class UUIDConverter implements Converter<UUID, String>`

Or when needed

`class UUIDConverter implements Converter<UUID, byte[]>`

You have to register this as a bean in your context.

Comment: Unfortunately I still see the exception after I register this converter.

Comment: However, your answer led me to the correct solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42915576/redis-how-to-configure-custom-conversions. We need to register a RedisCustomConversions bean. If you update your answer with this information, I will accept it. Thanks.