# Spring Data Redis - @Indexed UUID

Tags: spring-boot, indexing, redis, spring-data, uuid

I would like to create an index on a UUID field of my entity object, but the index is not created (e.g. order:user does not exist in redis)

```
@RedisHash("order")
public class Order {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Indexed
    private UUID user;

    ...

}
```

If I change the type of the field to String, the index is created.

Note: RedisCustomConversions for UUIDs is set: [Spring Data Redis - UUID id - ConverterNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867973/spring-data-redis-uuid-id-converternotfoundexception)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Do you have any workaround?

Comment: I haven't found one.